# Active Report6 :Devide single detail

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reporting, activereports

i have some records in detail format like these:
ID       Fullname        time
1        m wilson       12:05
2        sara Gold      15:05
3        sherry Wing    17:54
4        steeve Yeld    18:02
5        Djavad Brown   10:33
6        Layla Habib    07:11

in  a simple report i have these in printing report but i want my records to print like these :

ID       Fullname        time    ID       Fullname        time
1        m wilson       12:05    4        steeve Yeld    18:02
2        sara Gold      15:05    5        Djavad Brown   10:33
3        sherry Wing    17:54    6        Layla Habib    07:11

i mean i want my reords to print side by side in a page until my page end not below each other

Comment: there is no code there every thing is in visual mode

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you want to use Column Layout.

set the Detail.ColumnCount property to 2 then set the direction to either horizontal then vertical or vertical then horizontal.

http://arhelp.grapecity.com/webhelp/AR9/index.html#GrapeCity.ActiveReports.v9~GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.Detail~ColumnCount.html

hope this helps.

Comment: i think this is the solution but is there any example of this code?

Comment: can you please contact our support team activereports.support at grapecity.com and they can help you with a sample project based on your requirements.

Comment: thnaks i found one .that was the solution .thank you so much